# Is using css * selector to fit everything in webkit uiview for iPhone a good idea?

Tags: ios, css, uiview, webkit

I'm making an RSS reader and in order to display the images within the horizontal width, I'm appending the following CSS code to the HTML content:

```
<html><style type='text/css'>* 
{ max-width: 100%%  !important; 
width: auto  !important; 
height: auto  !important; }
</style><body>%@</body></html>
```

Is it a good idea? The reason for using * instead of img tag is that, when you use a caption div around an image (like wordpress does), then that image goes out of the horizontal bounds.

Will using this break anything?

Comment: Would it break anything to *only* apply it to img elements?

Comment: @cimmanon I had applied it to only img tags. But when the image was in a div (for eg. wordpress captions) the css selector didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

The downside that I first think of when I read this, is that the * selector can be very intensive sometimes, since it is selecting ALL elements.

On mobile that could be an issue.

But other than that I don't see any problems with using it, not the best practice, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using it on an iPhone app, so hardware wise I doubt if it will be a problem. Is there any good alternative to catch all images? (Even those, nested within a div)

Comment: You could try selecting all the classes then applying your style to them. ex: #id1.class1 {code code code;}

Comment: The thing is, I'm using several different sites and it wouldn't be possible to pick out such classes for every case.